bitwig-studio window disappears after screen lock but keeps running (Debian linux, Nvidia, xfce)
I have been using bitwig studio for a long time on Linux with few problems up until the last release, version 5.2. This version switched to using Vulkan for the UI. My desktop has an nvidia video card and runs the closed source Nvidia drivers. I use xfce desktop and compositing is enabled. All this works fine and there are no issues with any other software.
What happens is that bitwig starts up ok and all works up until I lock the screen. When I unlock the screen, the bitwig ui is invisible. The program is still running, playing notes on a MIDI keyboard makes sound and moving the mouse around where the UI was will cause the pointer to change and clicking sometimes makes menus appear although they seem unresponsive. The bitwig icon appears in the taskbar but clicking it doesnt do anything useful and if I ALT-Tab I can see an image that has the bitwig logo and is the right shape but instead of a miniature image of the UI it is instead like a snapshot of another part of the screen.
I run a very similar installation on a laptop with an embedded Intel video chip and it works fine. I have tried both the Debian supplied Nvidia drivers (version 535) and Nvidia's own PPA (v560).
I think the issue lies somewhere between the Nvidia drivers and xfce/compositing but I don't have a clue how to troubleshoot. Any suggestions would be really welcome.

Actually I did find something in the bitwig log - after unlocking the screen it seems to have written a bunch of log entries of the form:
Failed vulkan call. Error: -4, QueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submitInfo, fence)
[2024-8-16 4:17:14.944 skia error] Couldn't create GPU offsrceen with pixels 81x81 0
[2024-8-16 4:17:14.944 skia error] Couldn't create GPU offscreen with pixels 81x81, skia color type: 1
[2024-8-16 4:17:14.944 skia error] Couldn't create GPU offsrceen 81x81 2
